# How to keep spaces in caesar cipher program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am programming a Caeser Cipher encoder/decoder for my computer science class in Python 3 and I'm struggling to find out how to exclude spaces when each character is shifted.

```
message = input("type in a message")
messageInt = float(input("type in an integer"))
newStrs = []

for letter in message:
    x = ord(letter)
    x = int(x + messageInt)
    newStrs.append(chr(x))

print("".join(newStrs))
```

This happends when I try to use an example sentance with spaces, I've tried looking online for answers but I wasn't able to find anything that seemed to work in Python 3 or would output what my teacher expects.

```
type in a message hello there
type in an integer 3
#khoor#wkhuh

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Note, as I said in comment of one of the answers you got, you have another problem (not directly related to your question): Caesar cipher "rotates" letters. In your example, if you try to encode `how are you`, you'll have a problem with `y`. Because `chr(ord(y)+3)` is not a letter. You are supposed to encode `y` as `b` (if shift is 3: a→d, b→e, c→f, d→g, e→h, ..., v→y, w→z, x→a, y→b, z→c)

Comment: The answers you got kept your operation as is, and therefore kept this error as is... (edit: just now, I see that Dexty has updated their answer to include a correction to that bug; so, whatever answer you select, see Dexty's answer for a way to solve this)

Comment: @chrslg I have to admit I didn't notice that (shame on me and thanks for your comment!)

Comment: @chrslg Didn't notice this either, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude spaces when shifting the characters in your message, you can simply add an if statement to your loop that checks if the current letter is a space. If it is, you can skip the shifting step and just append the space to the newStrs list.

I modified your code as an example (code updated):

```
# Get the message and shift amount from the user
message = input("type in a message: ")
shift = int(input("type in an integer: "))

# Create a list to store the shifted characters
new_str = []

# Iterate through each character in the message
for letter in message:
    # Check if the character is a space
    if letter == " ":
        # If it is, append a space to the new string and skip the rest of the loop
        new_str.append(" ")
        continue

    # Shift the character by the specified amount
    # First, get the ASCII value of the character
    x = ord(letter)
    # Shift the character and wrap around the alphabet if necessary
    x = (x + shift - 97) % 26 + 97
    # Convert the shifted ASCII value back to a character and append it to the new string
    new_str.append(chr(x))

# Join the shifted characters into a single string and print it
print("".join(new_str))
```

If you are wondering whats going on with

```
x = (x + shift - 97) % 26 + 97
```

This will shift all characters except spaces, so the output will preserve the spaces in the original message.

```
x = (x + shift - 97) % 26 + 97
```

This line of code is used to shift the ASCII value of a character by a specified amount and wrap around the alphabet if necessary.

First, the value of x is added to the value of shift:

```
x + shift
```

Then, 97 is subtracted from the result:

```
x + shift - 97
```

The result is then passed to the % operator, which returns the remainder of the division of the left operand by the right operand. In this case, the remainder of the division of x + shift - 97 by 26 is calculated:

```
(x + shift - 97) % 26
```

Finally, 97 is added back to the result:

```
(x + shift - 97) % 26 + 97
```

This has the effect of shifting the character by the specified amount, wrapping around the alphabet if necessary, and ensuring that the resulting ASCII value is in the range 97 to 122 (inclusive).

For example, if the value of x is 120 (the ASCII value of 'x'), the value of shift is 3, and the line of code is executed, the following steps will be taken:

120 + 3 = 123
123 - 97 = 26
26 % 26 = 0
0 + 97 = 97

The final result, 97, is the ASCII value of 'a', so the resulting character will be 'a'.

Comment: Upvoted because you tried to keep the code as close as possible from OP's one, while adding the needed modification. But that said, this code suffer from another problem (which is not the object of the question) present in OP's: it would not work if letter+shift goes over `z`. So, whatever the shift is (except 0), you can't encode z.

Comment: Shifting, instead of `chr(ord(letter)+messageInt)` (which summarize the 3 lines) should be `x=ord(letter)-ord('a')` `x=(x+messageInt)%26`, `newStrs.append(ord('a')+x)`

Comment: Also (again, a problem in OP's code), messageInt should be parse as `int(input(...))` not `float(input(...))`. Which would spare the `int` conversion of `x+messageInt` later.

Comment: I have updated the code and added some comments. Thanks to @chrslg for pointing this out. I tried keeping it as simple as possible, as the OP is clearly a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple list comprehension with a ternary to check for the spaces:

```
message = input("type in a message")
messageInt = int(input("type in an integer"))

print("".join([c if c == ' ' else chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+messageInt)%26+ord('a')) for c in message]))
```

You can easily generalize to a whitelist of characters using a `set`:

```
keep = set(' .,?!')
print("".join([c if c in keep else chr((ord(c)-ord('a')+messageInt)%26+ord('a')) for c in message]))
```

Output:

```
khoor wkhuh
```

Comment: I would say this is too advanced for his level of code, however a good answer!

Comment: @Dexty it's never too early to learn list comprehensions IMO, one of the best python features ;)

Comment: I feel like there is no such thing as too advanced for an SO answer... just as there is no such thing as too basic / simple answer... you never know who is going to visit this page in the future and what their skill level might be.

Comment: I can use this in my code, but the teacher will definitely know that I didn't come up with this on my own. He did encourage us to look up answers online, so I think I can definitely justify using a more advanced answer.

Comment: You can show both and explain that the list comprehension is more efficient. This the whole class will have learned something ;)